# Gravity value for real world replication of ball falling

Tags: physics, scenekit, gravity

Within Scene Kit's physics, what value for gravity should create the same rate of acceleration we experience in the real world if a ball is dropped?

Comment: one that equals 9,813 m over seconds^2 in the reference frame of this engine ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default gravity for SceneKit physics is already `(0, -9.8, 0)`, which may sound like a familiar figure to anyone used to real-world physics.

However, the units of distance and size in SceneKit are entirely arbitrary — at least, up until the point where you need different sizes to be consistent with one another, or get physics to behave a certain way.

So you have two choices:

1. Leave the default gravity as-is, and size and position elements of your scene such that 1 unit = 1 meter.
2. Size and position things however you like, then work out a conversion from whatever system you're using for that to meters so you can set the scene's `physicsWorld.gravity` to 9.8 meters per second squared in your system.

Comment: Yes, 9.8 makes a lot of sense to me, and I was hoping it would behave similar to what we know and feel. However all balls I make with this gravity setting fall like they're on a planet with far less gravity than the moon. They take a minute to reach the bottom of the screen.

Comment: then waht about to jsut play around a bit and try some other bigger values? Is this a pixel value or an pixel independent value btw?

Comment: There are no pixels in 3D space.

Comment: argh, units were way off! Had a play field the length of an airport runway.

Comment: balls were the size of four city blocks.